# GNU Nano sort out integers in files

Tags: linux, sorting, gnu, nano

I have a problem working with GNU Nano program code. This is my task:

> Generate 100 files and in each one has to be one number(shuf -i1-1000 - n1). Then scan files and write numbers ascending order to a file named "output.txt".

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir files
find /etc/ -name "*.txt"|xargs du -h >output.txt
for x in {1..100}
do
shuf -i 1-1000 -n 1 > files/$x.txt
done
for x in {1..100}
do
input=$(cat files/$x.txt)
done
```

I wanted to ask how to sort out numbers which are in files and write them all to output.txt file?

Thanks

Comment: How is the question related to nano?

Comment: Why do you search for *.txt files in /etc?

Comment: and what does `output.txt` have to do with the rest of the code? AND you never use the assignment to the var `input`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sort` to sort the numbers.

```
#! /bin/bash
mkdir files
shuf -i1-1000 -n100 | for i in {1..100} ; do
    read n
    echo $n > files/$i.txt
done
sort -n files/*.txt > files/output.txt
```